# upgrading code from iPhone 3 to iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

Considering that the iPhone 4 has a much higher screen resolution than iPhone 3 - 
How can I port my code to iPhone 4.

Won't recompiling it change the appearance of images, controls, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

The provided UI elements should take care of the scaling for you. For anything you render, you'll need to take into account the screen resolution and scale accordingly. You might want to look at :

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreens/SupportingHiResScreens.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH15-SW1

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you already know this, but just in case you don't: you should be sure to include larger assets in your XCode project with @2x before their file extensions. For example: icon@2x.png. @2x tells iOS to use the larger version of the asset for Retina and iPad displays.

Comment: No I don't know this. sorry. I have only written code for iPhone 3. So If I have a splash screen 320X460 called splash.png that works well for iPhone 3, what should I do to build the project for iPhone 4? Thanks for your answer

Comment: So you need another copy of that image at double resolution and need to name whatever@2x.png. Assuming, that there are not other issues in your app, that should work. Sorry for the delay in replying.